# How do you lengthen a redstone button signal in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I made a little redstone circuit to open a door (using pistons) with a button, but I was wondering how I could make the door stay open  a little longer. I don't want to use a lever as I want it to close automatically after.

I thought of running parallel redstone delayers, with gradual delays, but I wanted to know if there is something more compact?

Comment: FYI answer below works in 1.8. Also, if doors just stay open, the delay line isn't long enough. For me, the hardest part was routing the delay circuit so it didn't interfere with the opening circuit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The words *compact* and *Redstone* don't usually go together :) There could be something simpler than this, probably using some weird combination of water, pistons, and chewing gum, but this is the best I can come up with: a basic delay circuit (from the wiki):

[image: redstone circuit diagram]
[image: minecraft screenshot]

In the screenshot, there is actually a pressure plate on the right, bit hard to see. I prefer not to use buttons, when running for my life. :)

Comment: @MadJawa, you're welcome, glad it helped. One minor point - I personally, usually wait a day or so before checkmarking an answer, to see what shows up. Be aware if a *better* answer shows up (it could happen :) , you can move the checkmark to it.

Comment: Wups - diagram was *missing* one redstone wire on the ground (although it's visible in the screenshot) - **fixed**. (Also rotated it to match screenshot).

Comment: upvote for "chewing gum".  (okay actually for in-game screenshot, rotating redstone layout to match, and taking the time to ensure completeness... i guess "chewing gum" just made me comment!)

also, when running for your life, pressure plates won't save you... they react to mobs also.

Comment: Heh - thanks for the upvote, and comment, @EdGruberman. And yeah, I know mobs can use pressure plates, I just happened to build my test circuit with a plate a while back... I do put a plate just *inside* my doors, though, so they close when I run through. And you *could* use an external pressure plate - you'd just need to connect it to an RS-NOR + AND-gate circuit *instead* of the door. Connect the AND output to the door, and you have a single-use pressure plate, that doesn't re-activate until you toggle the RS-NOR from inside...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what program do you use to make your schematics? I used to use Baezon's Redstone Simulator but it was never updated with repeaters. Or do you draw them *by hand*?

Comment: @Kevin Y, not exactly by hand - I cut/pasted a grid and the symbols from the wiki, and use Paint Shop Pro to cut/paste the correct symbol to a blank grid. I did have to add the numbers 1-4 to a blank repeater. Also - this design's delay *can be extended* by adding more repeaters on the left edge, same as yours. :)

Comment: That sounds like too much work. :/ Hopefully somebody will eventually make an updated Redstone simulator.

Comment: @Kevin Y, sure, if I had your 15K karma, I might not work as hard, but at a mere *1K*, I have to scramble for every point - so cut/paste, it is. :)

Comment: Well, you got an upvote from me. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you need a really long delay, you can use my personal favourite design, created by Minecraftaddict.

[image]
[image]

This circuit is featured in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ_lywyLVD0) of his. I think the design is nice because you can make the delay *a lot* longer, simply by extending the part with repeaters. Unfortunately, this circuit does not involve chewing gum either.

---

Also, in case anybody else who visits this question needs a very long delay, here is another circuit that provides an *even longer* delay (this is probably the most delay you'll ever need):

Comment: Just to note the obvious, the design I posted can *also* have a longer delay, by adding repeaters on the left edge (and moving the connecting redstone wires further).

Comment: I guess my answer wasn't phrased very well. What I *meant* to say was this design creates a lot of extra delay per repeater added – more than traditional pulse lengtheners.

Comment: Could be, I'm not up on traditional pulse lengtheners :) But this design is conceptually similar to the design I posted - in the video, he states that it uses an RS-NOR latch (just a vertical version). Although the more compact latch allows for two more repeaters on the top edge than my posted design - if I *extend* my design to the left, it would add the same delay factor as extending this one.

Comment: @agf, my comment was referring to the *first* design - the second delay circuit/video (which I presume you mean), was added a *month* after my comment... :)

Comment: @Cyclops My mistake :)

Answer (score 4):

A wooden button will give a longer delay than a stone button*. If you want even longer then I suggest a pulse extender which are all over the other answers.

Rt = Redstone ticks:

- Stone button = 10Rt (1s)
- Wooden button = 15Rt (1.5s)

Comment: This question is almost 5 years old, and your answer doesn't seem to add anything worthwhile. Try not to answer just for the sake of it.

Comment: He wanted a longer button pulse so I made a suggestion. Though I will admit I didn't notice the age of the post.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Necroing is fine on SE if the answer adds something new and useful, which if someone just wanted an extra half second of delay making a wooden button would be much simpler than a redstone circuit.

Comment: @Namfuak That's a fair point. However, I feel this kind of information is better suited to a comment to an answer rather than its own answer. But maybe I haven't quite grasped how this site works yet.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I could see it going either way if the answer was new, but since it is unlikely to be edited in to an existing answer at this point a new answer means it isn't hidden behind discussion.  This answer could be improved if it had the exact delay difference, though.

Comment: Difference added. But do you have to have this conversation? What does it achieve?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I've found is to hook button number 1 up to a dispenser full of arrows which shoots at button number 2. The arrow hits button number 2 and despawns after 1 minute, extending the timing of your button to a minute.[image]

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create a toggle flip flop (as you will have read about if you have read the official redstone guide) and then put a chain of repeaters to activate it again.