# How can I make the effects of button pushes last longer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you lengthen a redstone button signal in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26961/how-do-you-lengthen-a-redstone-button-signal-in-minecraft)

I am trying to create a piston-powered [3 x 4 doorway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JBwB.png) (with no visible pistons!).

I have tested my machine with manually activating the pistons, and am now looking to automate the process so it activates on a remote button push. Unfortunately for me, the actual order is pretty complex.

For example, here's the sequence of commands needed to close the door. (I have 5 redstone torch locations that need to provide power at separate times for the closing to work. Torch 4 isn't involved in the closing):

```
   5 on
   1 on
   3 on
   5 off
   3 off
   1 off
   2 on
   2 off
```

So here's the ultimate question:

How do I extend the effects of a button press to last longer than normal? Things triggered by buttons normally stop receiving power in the same order they started it, which can't happen in the sequence above, as 3 and 1 need to happen in reverse order.

Comment: And now I see this is a duplicate question. Don't mind me.

Comment: And you have 45K? :)

Comment: @Cyclops The problem was that I started the post with a different question in mind, but as I continued to write it out, I answered some of my own questions, and gradually pared the question down to one, already, answered question. :P