# How to make a redstone signal last longer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-mods

I want to create a big facility in my minecraft world for storage purposes etc, and i want to make doors that can be opened with a button. But it usually will close in front of my face or last a short time not enough for my friends and me to go through.

Is it possible to make a button that would open the doors for maybe 10 seconds? And after the time runs out they would simply close behind us.

If the above isn't possible, maybe it's possible to make doors that would open when the player walks close to them, and stay opened until there's no player in sight of the door. Maybe it's possible to do with command blocks OR either mods. If there's a mod for this on 1.16.4 could someone link it here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you lengthen a redstone button signal in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26961/how-do-you-lengthen-a-redstone-button-signal-in-minecraft)

Answer (score -1):

Use a lever, maybe? If the button isn’t crucial to the build, and it could be easily switched with a lever, that could work. As for the problem of breaking a red stone clock automatically, you could use a dispenser with a water bucket that’s strategically placed to break one redstone dust, but then you’d have to run a command to place the redstone dust back and that can get complicated, especially if it’s a survival world and you’d rather not use commands.

Comment: Yeah i know they give off a redstone signal, but the problem is we want to make the button to make the door close behind us. When there are levers on both sides you kinda have to first switch the other one, and then the second one for the door to close. i thought i could make a redstone clock that would activate when i click the button, but i don't know any way a redstone clock could be stopped wihout beraking it completely.